How to add custom content to products endpoint?
In magento 2.4.6 I have a custom module that adds some configuration in the admin panel. I also have a Helper/Data.php with methods to collect the value of each field of this configuration.
On the other hand I am using this endpoint to obtain product data:

http://domain.com/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1

and its output is like this:
{
"items": [
    {
        "id": 266,
        "sku": "TEST",
        "name": "Test product",
        "attribute_set_id": 4,
        "price": 0.006001,
        "status": 1,
        "visibility": 4,
        "type_id": "simple",
        "created_at": "2023-06-07 10:24:30",
        "updated_at": "2024-05-31 09:31:53",
        "weight": 1,
        "extension_attributes": {
            "website_ids": [
                1,
                4
            ],
            "category_links": [
                {
                    "position": -681624,
                    "category_id": "2"
                },
                {
                    "position": 25,
                    "category_id": "5"
                }
            ]
        },
        "product_links": [],
        "options": [],
        "media_gallery_entries": [
            {
                "id": 65,
                "media_type": "image",
                "label": "Test image",
                "position": 1,
                "disabled": false,
                "types": [
                    "image",
                    "small_image"
                ],
                "file": "/j/p/jp.png"
            }
        ],
        "tier_prices": [],
        "custom_attributes": [
            {
                "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
                "value": "2"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "category_ids",
                "value": [
                    "2",
                    "5"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
],
"search_criteria": {
    "filter_groups": [
        {
            "filters": [
                {
                    "field": "status",
                    "value": "1",
                    "condition_type": "eq"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"total_count": 117

}
I need to add in a different node, such as search_criteria or total_count, the content of the module configuration like this:
{
"items": [
    {
        "id": 266,
        "sku": "TEST",
        "name": "Test product",
        "attribute_set_id": 4,
        "price": 0.006001,
        "status": 1,
        "visibility": 4,
        "type_id": "simple",
        "created_at": "2023-06-07 10:24:30",
        "updated_at": "2024-05-31 09:31:53",
        "weight": 1,
        "extension_attributes": {
            "website_ids": [
                1,
                4
            ],
            "category_links": [
                {
                    "position": -681624,
                    "category_id": "2"
                },
                {
                    "position": 25,
                    "category_id": "5"
                }
            ]
        },
        "product_links": [],
        "options": [],
        "media_gallery_entries": [
            {
                "id": 65,
                "media_type": "image",
                "label": "Test image",
                "position": 1,
                "disabled": false,
                "types": [
                    "image",
                    "small_image"
                ],
                "file": "/j/p/jp.png"
            }
        ],
        "tier_prices": [],
        "custom_attributes": [
            {
                "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
                "value": "2"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "category_ids",
                "value": [
                    "2",
                    "5"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
],
"search_criteria": {
    "filter_groups": [
        {
            "filters": [
                {
                    "field": "status",
                    "value": "1",
                    "condition_type": "eq"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"total_count": 117,
"fields_config": {
    "field1" : {
        "value": "field 1 value"
    },
    "field2" : {
        "value": "field 2 value"
    }
}

}
How can I add this content to already existing Magento endpoint? Thanks in advance
